# How to extract only part of string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a following string and I want to extract image123.jpg.

```
..here_can_be_any_length "and_here_any_length/image123.jpg" and_here_also_any_length
```

image123 can be any length (newimage123456 etc) and with extension of jpg, jpeg, gif or png.

I assume I need to use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), but I am not really sure and like to know how to code it or if there are any other ways or function I can use.

Comment: In case the surrounding is markup, consider using DOM, XPath or SimpleHTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
if(preg_match('#".*?\/(.*?)"#',$str,$matches)) {
   $filename = $matches[1];
}
```

Alternatively you can extract the entire path between the double quotes using preg_match and then extract the filename from the path using the function [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
if(preg_match('#"(.*?)"#',$str,$matches)) {
    $path = $matches[1]; // extract the entire path.
    $filename =  basename ($path); // extract file name from path.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What about something like this :

```
$str = '..here_can_be_any_length "and_here_any_length/image123.jpg" and_here_also_any_length';
$m = array();
if (preg_match('#".*?/([^\.]+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png))"#', $str, $m)) {
    var_dump($m[1]);
}
```

Which, here, will give you :

```
string(12) "image123.jpg"
```

I suppose the pattern could be a bit simpler -- you could not check the extension, for instance, and accept any kind of file ; but not sure it would suit your needs.

Basically, here, the pattern :

- starts with a `"`
- takes any number of characters until a `/` : `.*?/`
- then takes any number of characters that are not a `.` : `[^\.]+`
- then checks for a dot : `\.`
- then comes the extension -- one of those you decided to allow : `(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)`
- and, finally, the end of pattern, another `"`

And the whole portion of the pattern that corresponds to the filename is surrounded by `()`, so it's captured -- returned in `$m`

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '..here_can_be_any_length "and_here_any_length/image123.jpg" and_here_also_any_length';
$data = explode('"',$string);
$basename = basename($data[1]);
```